# Casting ScriptBlock as Action[T] for Generic.List[T] ForEach method

Tags: powershell, generics, delegates, action, powershell-4.0

I am having problems using the ForEach() method on Generic.List[T] in PowerShell. I have tested some of the other methods with these anonymous delegates (C# lambda expressions) on the Generic.List[T] and they work. Following is my code assuming the list[T] has values:

```
$list = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[uint32]
$rng = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider
$sysArray1 = @()

for ( $i = 0; $i -lt 10; $i++ )
{    
    $byte = New-Object byte[] 4
    $rng.GetBytes($byte)
    $list.Add( [bitconverter]::ToUInt32( $byte,0 ) )
    $sysArray1 += [bitconverter]::ToUInt32( $byte,0 )
}
```

With the `$sysArray1` I am able to use the ForEach() method; however, with `$list` I am not.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $sysArray1.ForEach({($_.ToString() + " Hello, World!")})
230848998 Hello, World!
1472227127 Hello, World!
2436917759 Hello, World!
797599365 Hello, World!
3872804216 Hello, World!
453721367 Hello, World!
46463291 Hello, World!
2921221794 Hello, World!
627551225 Hello, World!
1839786036 Hello, World!

PS C:\Windows\system32> $list.ForEach({$_.ToString() + " Hello, World!"})
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:16
+ $list.ForEach({$_.ToString() + " Hello, World!"})
+                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

The above error occurs as many times as the size of the List[T]. Also I cannot cast the ScriptBlocks in either approach as `[Action[T]]`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `{$_.ToString() + " Hello, World!"}` -> `{Write-Host ($args[0].ToString() + " Hello, World!")}`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This absolutely works. I am curious as to why `Write-Host` works, but `Write-Output` does not. Also, is there a general rule here as to why `$args` is used? Also, why does the built-in array `@()` work with any expression I use versus a `List[T]`?

Comment: `[Action[T]]` return [void], thus whatever you output will be casted as [void]. `$args` is used when you want to refer arguments of your `ScriptBlock`. `$sysArray1.ForEach` and `$list.ForEach` are two different things, and second one know nothing about PowerShell.

Comment: Thank you very much. That makes very much sense. If you post as an answer, I'll mark it as one.