# How do I properly use ForEach() statement of List?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I'm confused what I'm doing wrong in ForEach method syntax of List?

```
PS D:\ntt> $nicInfo.IpConfigurations.Count
2
PS D:\ntt> $nicInfo.IpConfigurations[0]

PrivateIpAddressVersion Name      Primary PrivateIpAddress PrivateIpAllocationMethod Subnet Name PublicIpAddress Name ProvisioningState
----------------------- ----      ------- ---------------- ------------------------- ----------- -------------------- -----------------
IPv4                    ipconfig1 True    10.233.0.4       Dynamic                                                    Succeeded


PS D:\ntt> $nicInfo.IpConfigurations.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     List`1                                   System.Object


PS D:\ntt> $nicInfo.IpConfigurations.ForEach({$_})
PS D:\ntt>
```

Comment: How did you create the object? Are you sure this method exists? What about using a [standard foreach loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-5.1)?

Comment: This object created by return of another cmdlet. Piping to `Foreach-Object` works fine

Comment: that looks like a bug! [*grin*] the `.Where` method works. neither `$_` nor `$PSItem` seem to work in a `.ForEach()` when the collection type is a Generic.List. how interesting ... using a `Write-Host` sends output to the host, but not the `$_` stuff. using `Write-Output` shows nothing at all. it looks like a glitch in how the output stream is handled.

Comment: This works though `...GetEnumerator().Foreach()`

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? `ForEach` is executed for its side-effects and you don't appear to have any. What does `$nicInfo.IpConfigurations.ForEach({param($i) write-host "$i"})` do?

Comment: I want to do some data manipulation in foreach statement, example is just and example.

Comment: @GregorySuvalian `List<T>` have its own [`ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.foreach) method. Because of this it is preferred over `ForEach` PowerShell adds to collections.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **problem** is that **[PowerShell's own `.ForEach()` collection method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays#foreach) is *preempted* by [the `List<T>` type's own `.ForEach()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.foreach)** in this case:

- PowerShell's own `.ForEach({ ... })`:

  - defines `$_` as the input object at hand for the script-block argument (`{ ... }`)
  - passes any output produced inside the script block through (to PowerShell's success output stream).
- By contrast, `List<T>`'s `.ForEach({ ... })` converts the script block to an `Action<T>` delegate, which has the following implications:

  - The delegate doesn't know about `$_` inside the script block and instead receives a single *argument* that must be accessed as `$args[0]`.
  - *Output* from the script block is *ignored*, because an `Action<T>` delegate by definition has *no return value*.

    - While you can produce *host* (console) output with `Write-Host` from within the script block, such output cannot be used *programmatically*, because it bypasses PowerShell's output streams and can therefore neither be captured nor redirected.

<sup>Tip of the hat to [PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral) for providing the crucial pointers in comments.</sup>

**Workarounds**:

- If the script block you pass to `.ForEach()` *need not produce any output*, all that's needed is to use `$args[0]` in lieu of `$_` in your script block, though you may still opt to use one of the other workarounds below in order to avoid confusion.
- **If output *is* needed, the simplest solution is to convert the `List<T>` instance to an *array* with `.ToArray()` first**, on which `.ForEach()` works as expected; a simplified example:

  ```
  $list = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]] ('foo', 'bar')
  $list.ToArray().ForEach({ $_ + '!' }) # Note the .ToArray() call.
  ```

  The above produces `'foo!', 'bar!'`, as expected.

  - **Alternatively**, you may use:

    - a `foreach` loop to process the list items, which means you must pick an iteration variable name and refer to that instead of `$_` in the loop body; e.g.:
      `foreach ($itm in $list) { $itm + '!' }`
    - or `ForEach-Object` in a *pipeline* (slower, but doesn't require changing the script block), as shown in [No Refunds No Returns' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53825935/45375); e.g.:
      `$list | ForEach-Object { $_ + '!' }`

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do something with each item in the collection?  Do you want to do something like this:

```
$nicInfo.IpConfigurations | ForEach-Object {
  $ipConfiguration = $_
  write-Output $ipConfiguration
  # do more stuff with this $ipConfiguration
}
```

Comment: ᐩ1 for an effective _workaround_, though it would help to explain why it is needed.

Comment: That's not the explanation, because PowerShell offers a `.ForEach()` _method_ on all collections (and even scalars) in v4+. The only reason for the `ForEach-Object` workaround is that in this case the _specific collection type has its own_ `.ForEach()` method, which _preempts_ PowerShell's. To see PowerShell's `.ForEach()` in action, try  `(1..3).ForEach({ $_+1 })` or `([collections.arraylist] (1..3)).ForEach({ $_+1 })` or `'foo'.ForEach({ $_+'!' })`

Answer (score 1):

Just for your reference, you can use this code for list.ForEach().

```
$nicInfo.IpConfigurations.ForEach({write-host $args[0].ToString()})
```

And I test it myself, it works. Sample code as below:

```
$s=New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[string]
$s.Add("hello_1")
$s.Add("hello_2")
$s.Add("hello_3")
$s.ForEach({write-host $args[0].ToString()})
```

Test result as below:

[image]

As well as I found this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48105720/casting-scriptblock-as-actiont-for-generic-listt-foreach-method), @PetSerAl explained very well there.

Comment: Using `$args[0]` instead of `$_` solves the _input_ problem, but using `Write-Host` doesn't solve the _output_ problem, because it prints directly to the _host_ (console), meaning that  you'll neither be able to capture nor redirect that output.

Comment: @mklement0, thanks for pointing it out, I didn't realize that.